# How to recover Lost drives?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

I installed ubuntu by overwriting windows 7.
I didnt knew it would delete all my hard disk partitions and data.
Now there is only single drive which has ubuntu installed in it.
how to recover my lost drives and data?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry about your data loss.

Try follow instruction [from this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery). It doesn't guarantee 100% data recovery but I once have similar accident and able to recover most data I need by following that.

One thing to watch out for. Keep your affected drive usage as low as possible, any further use of the drive could worsen your chance of recovery. Better use a live CD or bootable USB.